# Is NSDictionary Defined?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, alloc

I have a NSDictionary that might be getting set inside a loop.  At the end of the loop I want to find out if the dictionary has been defined.  Here is an example:

```
NSDictionary *myDict;

for (int i=0; i < 100; i++){
    if (thisCondition){
        myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:etc, nil];
    }
}

if (myDict) {
     [self doSomething];
}
```

Unfortunately, the test of myDict passes every time, whether myDict has been alloc'ed or not.  Trying to pass any methods to myDict, like [myDict count], give a exc_bad_access because it has not been alloc'ed.  So it is kind of a no man's land.

Is there a way to accomplish this?  I realize I could switch to a NSMutableDictionary, define it, add to it in the loop, and test for a count, but that is not my preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you initialize your pointer to nil:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = nil;
```

otherwise, your check for a valid pointer may not work.

Comment: @Jakob Borg Why not *may*? In 1 out of 2^64 cases it **will** work.

Comment: you should add a 'break' inside your if clause--so you don't have to run through the rest of the cases

Comment: @Nikolai Yeah... Well, .000000000000000005 % success rate is empirically closer to "will fail" than "may fail".